# How to create a new head to the list in C?

Tags: c, pointers, struct

How to write a "add_first" function that will change head and return the value of a new variable without any changes in "main" function? 
Is it possible to do this without pass a pointer to the pointer variable (a double pointer)?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

struct node_t
{
    int value;
    struct node_t *next;
};

int add_first(struct node_t *);
void print_list(struct node_t *);

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    struct node_t *head = NULL ;
    int rand_val = add_first(head);
    printf("Value =  %d\n", rand_val);
    print_list(head);
}

int add_first(struct node_t *lista)
{
    lista = (struct node_t*)malloc(sizeof(struct node_t));
    srand(time(NULL)); 
    int val = (int)(rand() / (RAND_MAX + 1.0) * 100.0);
    lista->value = 10;
    lista->next = NULL;
    return val;
}

void print_list(struct node_t * head) {
    struct node_t * current = head;

    while (current != NULL) {
        printf("%d\n", current->value);
        current = current->next;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to write a "add_first" function that will change head and return the value of a new variable **without any changes in "main" function**?

Not possible to do the bolded part because there is no way to return the head of the list without changing `main` and `add_first`. If you lift that restriction, there are two ways. The first way is to pass a pointer to the poointer to the head of the list. `add_first` becomes this:

```
int add_first(struct node_t **lista)
{
    newHead = (struct node_t*)malloc(sizeof(struct node_t));
    srand(time(NULL)); 
    int val = (int)(rand() / (RAND_MAX + 1.0) * 100.0);
    newHead->value = 10;
    newHead->next = *lista;
    *lista = newHead;
    return val;
}
```

In `main`

```
int rand_val = add_first(&head);
```

It creates a new list head, links the existing list to its `next` and sets the passed in list to the new head.

The other way only works assuming that you *really* wanted to set the value in the new item to the value you are returning. In this case, you can return the new head of the list

```
(struct node_t *add_first(struct node_t *lista)
{
    newHead = (struct node_t*)malloc(sizeof(struct node_t));
    srand(time(NULL)); 
    newHead->value = (int)(rand() / (RAND_MAX + 1.0) * 100.0);
    newHead->next = lista;
    return newHead;
}
```

In `main`

```
head = add_first(head);
rand_val = head->value;
```